# How to load data from NSUserdefaults?

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

How do I check if there is already data stored in the `NSUserdefaults`?
right now the code crashes when it is trying to load not existing data.

I tried:

```
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *string = [ud objectForKey:@"scoreStringKey"];
if (string) 
{
    highScore = string.intValue;   
}
else
{        
    highScore = 0;
}
```

Comment: On which line does it crash and with what error?

Comment: How do you set value for key `scoreStringKey`?

Comment: Even if your string is @"", it will return `true` in the if condition and it will crash when you try to convert it to an integer.

Comment: @Desdenova you were right! the problem was the conversion to an integer value. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objectForKey` will return nil if no key found [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/objectForKey%3a)

intValue is a method not attribute. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/intValue)

```
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *string = [ud objectForKey:@"scoreStringKey"];
if (string != nil) 
{
    highScore = [string intValue];   <--- right way to convert into integer
}    
else
{        
    highScore = 0;
}
```